# Angular Directive for Jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am new to angular.
I am trying to make a directive around jquery UI datepicker with localization support for it.
So far I have found this link [Angular Directive for Datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/)

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
```

$.extend(
    {'dateFormat':'dd-mm-yy'},
    $.datepicker.regional['nl']
  )
);

But I have no idea how to use datepicker localization options there.
Normally, we need to include respective language file and then use setDefault() for $.datepicker but the problem is where do I put this code in angular directive?